# What happens when I release a upgrade with higher targeted sdk as previous version?

Tags: android, upgrade, target

`SoundPool` has a serious bug in it in Android 1.5. I fixed it with a workaround, but since it really limits my app, I want to target 1.6+ for the next version of it.

I am wondering: What happens when I release a upgrade that has a higher target SDK version then the previous version of my app? Will only 1.6+ users be able to upgrade their app? Or will also the 1.5 users be able to upgrade since they have the program already installed?

Anybody experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you answered one of my questions, I thought I'd take a look at your questions:-

From what I've read on the Android dev site:-

The manifest holds the MINIMUM version that the APK will support. Only users with the same version or higher of that SDK will be able to even see you App in the Market.

Therefore, to answer your question, YES, only users with OS 1.6+ Android will be able to upgrade. I released an app once, set to 1.6, and wondered why I was getting less downloads, then realised what I had done, set it back to 1.5, and all was well.

Is there anyway you could get the newer 1.6 source for soundpool, add that to your app, and use it when version 1.5 is detected (or, just use it all the time).

Lots of hassle I know, but just a thought.

Comment: Soundpool is native code, so I can't backport it.
However, I justditched soundpool for now, since it has some more stupid bugs.

Comment: Probably you are right. I doubt the user will get to install the app if it's not available for him, but have not seen any experience reported with changing the API version for updates.

Answer (score 0):

Havn't got any experience with this but that a 1.5 user can use an app targeted for minimum 1.6 seems highly unlikely. They will probably be informed that your app no longer supports their platform or just not recive the update.